# Route static not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-redux

Route `about-us` not working. Only works when I attaching some prefix to the route `Country`. How can I fix it. Thanks.

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute components={Home}/>
    <Route path=":country" components={Country}/>
    <Route path=":country/:city" components={City}/>
    <Route path="*" components={NotMatch}/>
    <Route path="about-us" components={AboutUs}/>
</Route>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap these 2 lines,

Instead of:

```
<Route path="*" components={NotMatch}/>
<Route path="about-us" components={AboutUs}/>
```

Use this:

```
<Route path="about-us" components={AboutUs}/>
<Route path="*" components={NotMatch}/>
```

And remove the `:` from route `country` and `country/:city`.

Like this:

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute components={Home}/>
    <Route path="country" components={Country}/>
    <Route path="country/:city" components={City}/>
    <Route path="about-us" components={AboutUs}/>
    <Route path="*" components={NotMatch}/>
</Route>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mayank Shukla. You gave me the right deriction.

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute components={Home}/>
    <Route path="/about-us" components={AboutUs}/>
    <Route path=":country" components={Country}/>
    <Route path=":country/:city" components={City}/>
    <Route path="*" components={NotMatch}/>
</Route>
```

This working.